# How to add sortable column for member list in Silverstripe admin?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am struggling to add sort functionality on one of my member summary fields in admin.

I have extended the Silverstripe member class using:

```
class MyMemberExtension extends DataExtension
```

I have added a few fields to the default gridfield in admin:

```
private static $db = array(
    'Organisation' => 'Varchar(100)'
);

private static $summary_fields = array( 
    'FirstName' => 'First Name', 
    'Surname' => 'Surname', 
    'Email' => 'Email', 
    'OrganisationName' => 'Organisation Name', 
    'LastVisited' => 'Last Visited',
    'NumVisit' => 'Num Visits'
);

private static $casting = array(
    'OrganisationName' => 'Varchar(100)'
);

public function getOrganisationName() {
    return $this->owner->Organisation; 
}
```

...and that all works nicely.

However, only the core fields like LastVisited are giving me sort arrows on the column headers.

I'm currently stuck as to how to implement the sort on my Organisation field. I tried adding :

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $grid = $fields->dataFieldByName('Organisation');
    $gridConfig = $grid->getConfig();
    $gridConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableHeader());
    return $fields;
}    

public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
    $form=parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

    $model = singleton($this->modelClass);

    // add sorting if we have a field for... 
    if (class_exists('GridFieldSortableRows')
        && $model->hasField('Organisation')
        && $gridField=$form->Fields()->dataFieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass))) {
        if($gridField instanceof GridField) {
            $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('Organisation'));
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

...to my class, but I'm not convinced these are even being called, as even if I just return null from these two functions nothing changes.

I have found a few answers that deal with extensions to ModelAdmin, but not for the core Member list. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure why you chose to have a getter named `OrganisationName`, where you could just as well use `Organisation` directly? That being said, I think your question is valid and might apply to different scenarios and/or field-types.

The Form-field that is being used to edit members is the `Members` GridField within `SecurityAdmin`. Luckily, there's an extension hook (`updateEditForm`) to modify the form fields of `SecurityAdmin`.

So in order to modify the sorting of the Members GridField, create an Extension like the following:

```
<?php

class MemberAdminExtension extends Extension
{
    public function updateEditForm(Form $form)
    {
        /** @var GridField $memberGridField */
        if ($memberGridField = $form->Fields()->dataFieldByName('Members')) {
            /** @var GridFieldSortableHeader $sortHeader */
            if ($sortHeader = $memberGridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldSortableHeader')) {
                // Map OrganisationName to the Organisation field
                $sortHeader->setFieldSorting([
                    'OrganisationName' => 'Organisation'
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And apply the extension via config to `SecurityAdmin`:

```
# Within _config/config.yml
SecurityAdmin:
  extensions:
    - MemberAdminExtension
```

After a `dev/build` your Member table should be sortable by `Organisation Name` as well…

Comment: Having the "getter" named OrganisationName proved to be the problem. I'm not sure why I did that, but due to your comment I removed it, commented out all my attempts to get Organisation to be sortable - and Silverstripe made it sortable by default!
I did test your answer as well though, by implementing it for a different custom field that did require a getter to format it. And it worked perfectly, cheers.